# Meaningless placeholder for tags on new sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, private-beta

When asking a question on a [new private beta](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/), the input field for tags has a rather meaningless placeholder:

> e.g. ()

I understand no tags can be recommended, but wouldn't it be better to just omit it in this case?

[image: screenshot]